# Building array for chart with for loop and multiple orWhen

Tags: mysql, laravel, for-loop, count

I'm building an array to show ratings in a chart for each day of the current week, using this loop

```
$ratings = collect([]);
$startOfWeek = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();        
for ($days_forwards = 0; $days_forwards <= 6; $days_forwards++) {
            $ratings->push(Rating::whereIn('song_id', $userSongs)
                    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($userAlbums) {
                        $query->whereIn('album_id', $userAlbums);
                    })
                    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($userArtists) {
                        $query->whereIn('artist_id', $userArtists);
                    })
                    ->whereDate('created_at', $startOfWeek->addDays($days_forwards))
                    ->count());
            $startOfWeek = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
        }
```

This works fine with just the first whereIn, but when I add the other two orWhere filters, the chart flattens out to 2 results for every day. I can't work out why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out in the end, nesting the orWhere() queries inside the first where(), like this;

```
for ($days_forwards = 0; $days_forwards <= 6; $days_forwards++) {
            $ratings->push(Rating::where(function ($query) use ($userSongs, $userAlbums, $userArtists) {
                        $query->whereIn('song_id', $userSongs)
                        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($userAlbums) {
                            $query->whereIn('album_id', $userAlbums);
                        })
                        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($userArtists) {
                            $query->whereIn('artist_id', $userArtists);
                        });
                    })
                    ->whereDate('created_at', $startOfWeek->addDays($days_forwards))
                    ->count());
            $startOfWeek = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
        }
```